# How do I control the position of objects

Tags: css, jsf, primefaces

I am trying to learn how to use templates in Web pages. Thanks to something I found on stackoverflow, I have the basics going. Now I want some control over the formatting. I found an example which looks nice so I thought I would use it to learn something. I'll show 2 images so the problem will be clear:

[image: original]
[image: my attempt]

I don't really care about the form itself. It just serves as an example to learn something. There are a couple of things I would like to control over:
1) Notice in the original that the Company Name is placed nicely with respect to the jpeg image. In my case it is stuck to the left.
2) In the original if I expand the Firefox window the form stays centered and there is white space on both sides. In my case the Primefaces controls take the whole window and they are too high, cutting off part of the jpeg image.

I saw the original uses style.css so I tried to copy and paste different items, but nothing gave me the control I'm looking for. I'll show the only thing in style.css which makes any difference:

```
body {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
background: #fff url(images/header.jpg) no-repeat center top;
font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
font-size: 12px;
color: #7c7c7c;
}
```

This is the beginning of the original form

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta name="keywords" content="" />
<meta name="description" content="" />
 <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
 <title>Xhtml18</title>
<link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" />
</head>
<body>
<div id="wrapper">
<div id="header-wrapper">
    <div id="header">
        <div id="logo">
            <h1><a href="#">Company <span>Name</span></a></h1>
            <p>Nice Slogan Goes Here</p>
        </div>
        <div id="menu">
            <ul>
                <li class="current_page_item"><a href="#">Homepage</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">ABOUT US</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">SERVICES</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">SUPPORT</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">CONTACT</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I tried putting in all the inner definitions, but they made no difference. I have my version much simpler

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html">
<h:head>
<title>Master template</title>
<link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" />
</h:head>
<h:body>
<div id="logo">
    <h1><a href="#">Company <span>Name</span></a></h1>
    <p>Nice Slogan Goes Here</p>
</div>
<ui:insert name="AreaOne">Default text</ui:insert>
</h:body>
</html>
```

Finally in my xhtml file the crucial step which allows me to do the templating

```
<h:body>
<ui:composition template="master.xhtml">
    <ui:define name="AreaOne">
```

So that the major point of templating seems to be working, just I need some more control over it. Sorry for the long message but I think I need it all to explain the problem.

EDIT:
I don't know how to add a file per se, so I'll spell it out as code

```
body {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
background: #fff url(images/header.jpg) no-repeat center top;
font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
font-size: 12px;
color: #7c7c7c;
}

h1, h2, h3 {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
font-weight: normal;
color: #000;
}

h1 {
font-size: 2em;
}

h2 {
font-size: 2.8em;
}

h3 {
font-size: 1.6em;
}

p, ul, ol {
margin-top: 0;
line-height: 180%;
}

ul, ol {
}

a {
text-decoration: none;
color: #419725;
}

a:hover {
}

#wrapper {
margin: 0 auto;
padding: 0;
}

/* Header */

#header-wrapper {
height: 234px;


}

#header {
width: 950px;
margin: 0 auto;
padding: 0px 0px 0px 30px;
}

/* Logo */

#logo {
float: left;
width: 500px;
margin: 0px;
padding: 30px 0px 0px 60px;
color: #f7f7f7;

}

#logo h1, #logo p {
}

#logo h1 {
padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
letter-spacing: -1px;
font-size: 3.8em;
background: redc;
}

#logo h1 span {
color: #efc527;
}

#logo p {
margin: 0;
padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
font-size: 16px;
color: #fff;
} 

#logo a {
border: none;
background: none;
text-decoration: none;
color: #f7f7f7;
}

/* Search */

#search {
float: left;
width: 280px;
height: 40px;
padding: 0px;
}

#search form {
height: 40px;
margin: 0;
padding: 0px 0 0 10px;
}

#search fieldset {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
border: none;
}

#search-text {
width: 170px;
padding: 6px 5px 2px 5px;
border: 1px solid #DEDEDE;
background: #FFFFFF;
text-transform: lowercase;
font: normal 11px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
color: #5D781D;
}

#search-submit {
width: 50px;
height: 22px;
border: none;
background: #e4e4e4;
color: #171d21;
}

/* Menu */

#menu {
float: right;
width: 950px;
height: 50px;
margin: 0 auto;
padding: 0;
}

#menu ul {
float: left;
margin: 0;
padding: 74px 0px 0px 0px;
list-style: none;
line-height: normal;
}

#menu li {
float: left;
}

#menu a {
display: block;
margin-right: 1px;
padding: 16px 20px 15px 20px;
text-decoration: none;
text-align: center;
text-transform: uppercase;
font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
font-size: 12px;
font-weight: bold;
color: #fff;
border: none;
}

#menu a:hover, #menu .current_page_item a {
background: #131618;
text-decoration: none;
color: #FFFFFF;
}

#menu .current_page_item a {
}

/* Page */

#page {
width: 990px;
margin: 0 auto;
padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
background: url(images/img03.jpg) repeat-y left top;
}

#page-bgtop {
padding: 40px 0px 20px 0px;
background: url(images/img02.jpg) no-repeat left top;
}
/* Content */

#content {
float: left;
width: 720px;
padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
}

.post {
margin-bottom: 40px;
border-bottom: 1px dotted #E7E2DC;
margin-right: 10px;
}

.post .title {
height: 41px;
padding: 7px 0px 0px 30px;
letter-spacing: -.5px;
}

.post .title a {
border: none;
color: #000;
 }

.post .meta {
margin-bottom: 30px;
padding: 0px 30px 0px 30px;
text-align: left;
font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
font-size: 13px;
font-weight: bold;
font-style: italic;
}

.post .meta .date {
float: left;
}

.post .meta .posted {
float: right;
}

.post .meta a {
}

.post .entry {
padding: 0px 30px 20px 30px;
padding-bottom: 20px;
text-align: justify;
}

.links {
padding-top: 20px;
font-size: 12px;
font-weight: bold;
}

/* Sidebar */

#sidebar {
float: right;
width: 240px;
margin: 0px;
padding: 0px 20px 0px 10px;
color: #fff;
}

#sidebar ul {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
list-style: none;
}

#sidebar li {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
}

#sidebar li ul {
margin: 0px 0px;
padding-bottom: 30px;
}

#sidebar li li {
line-height: 35px;
border-bottom: 1px dotted #E7E2DC;
margin: 0px 30px;
border-left: none;
}

#sidebar li li span {
display: block;
margin-top: -20px;
padding: 0;
font-size: 11px;
font-style: italic;
}

#sidebar li li a {
padding: 0px 0px 0px 15px;
}

#sidebar h2 {
height: 38px;
padding-left: 30px;
letter-spacing: -.5px;
font-size: 1.8em;
color: #fff;
}

#sidebar p {
margin: 0 0px;
padding: 0px 30px 20px 30px;
text-align: justify;
}

#sidebar a {
border: none;
color: #efc527;
}

#sidebar a:hover {
text-decoration: underline;
}

/* Calendar */

#calendar {
}

#calendar_wrap {
padding: 20px;
}

#calendar table {
width: 100%;
}

#calendar tbody td {
text-align: center;
}

#calendar #next {
text-align: right;
}

/* Footer */

#footer {
height: 50px;
margin: 0 auto;
padding: 0px 0 30px 0;
font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
border-top: 5px solid #4ac221;
width: 990px;
background: #262626;
}

#footer p {
margin: 0;
padding-top: 40px;
line-height: normal;
font-size: 9px;
text-transform: uppercase;
text-align: center;
color: #fff;
}

#footer a {
color: #fff;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `brackground` has the `center` attribute, that's why you've got your logo on the center and the text is not on it.

```
body {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
background: #fff url(images/header.jpg) no-repeat center top;
font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
font-size: 12px;
color: #7c7c7c;
}
```

You can remove the `center` attribute or you can move the text by doing something like that (just an example!)

```
<div align="center"><h1><a href="#">Company <span>Name</span></a></h1></div>
```

Then, to stop your primefaces' components to autoresize, you've got to override the default css.

I guess that you're using a PanelGrid, so you can try with

```
<p:panelGrid columns="2" style="width: 200px !important">....</p:panelGrid>
```

I'm not sure that `!important` is required, but basically you've got to give a fixed width to the component to stop it from auto-resizing

EDIT:

If you want to apply your style to every `p:panelGrid` component, you should consider overriding the whole css class.

Just take a look here to know the css class names of each primefaces component :

http://primefaces.googlecode.com/files/primefaces_users_guide_3_2.pdf

Comment: I did think of aligning the text as center, but you can see that in the original it is not centered. Somehow the author placed it at a given offset from the left of the jpeg. I haven't been able to figure out how he did it. You are correct about my using PanelGrid. I'll try playing with that in parallel and I'll look at your reference to see what I can learn from it.

Comment: If you want to make it like the example, remove the `center` attribute from the logo's css and try with something like this : 

`<div style="margin-left: 5%"><h1><a href="#">Company <span>Name</span></a></h1></div>` 

Play with that `5%` value and try also using `padding-left` instead of `margin-left`

Comment: This isn't critical to fix. I just thought it was something which everybody but me knows how to do. In the original example it is clever enough to know to offset the text with respect to the image. Both margin-left and padding-left calculate with respect to the page edge. Somehow the page knows what the size of the jpeg image is and everything is set to that value. If this isn't something which everybody but me knows then I can forget it. There is ample power in primefaces to come up with another solution.

Comment: Maybe posting the original css will help..Anyway, the page can't know the size of the image. Using percentual values helps you to set your dimensions relative to screen's resolution

Comment: While putting in the 4 spaces on each line I noticed that content and sidebar had widths to them. Perhaps it sums the 2 numbers together and THAT is what determines the overall width? Again, more than just learning whatever I can, I don't really care about this example. Primefaces has a nice layout object which I will try. I would like to know how I can put the text over the header object at a specific offset like is done in the original. Somehow it has got to know the width of the jpeg object and then I place the text with reference to that number. Assume that the jpeg is centered.

Comment: As in logo's css :

`float: left;
padding: 30px 0px 0px 60px;`

This will position your text to the left, leaving 30px from the top and 60 from the left (as is yhe example).

Having the image in the background has nothing to do with it. Indeed, you can try removing the background image from the example and you'll see that the text will keep its position even with no image

Comment: Thanks. I'll try it. I've gone to using Primefaces layout and now have a new set of problems. I've got to figure out what went wrong.

Comment: Open a new question about PrimeFaces' problems and don't forget to accept the answer if you think that it helped you :)

Comment: That was a stupid typo which gave me problems. I've been playing around with the Primefaces layout. I wanted to put the image into the north panel but I can't make it happen. If I use an <img> tag then the text is next to it, not inside it. It seems I definitely need the background attribute to I can write over it. Since I no longer see the image I am guessing that it gets put up and then the full screen layout writes over it. I haven't yet solved the problem but your answers certainly helped, I will happily accept your answer.

Comment: Well, your problem actually changed, so it's better to continue in a new question :) And yes, to write on an image you need to have it as a background, otherwise they will be just near with no overlay!